# How to test private helper(module) method in rspec

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, module, rspec-rails

I have a helper module named "AppHelper" and private method "sum" which I want to test using rspec.

For example:

```
module AppHelper
 private
 def sum(a,b)
   puts a+b
 end
end
```

Comment: I disagree with testing private methods. [More here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16197778/3784008).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to spec a private method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4154409/how-to-spec-a-private-method)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

create a dummy class and access private method using **.send(:private_method, args)**

**example**

obj = Class.new { extend AppHelper }
obj.send(:sum, 1,2)