# RSpec: Testing result from ActiveRecord::Base.connection

Tags: rspec, rspec-rails

I have the following method which is going to execute a lot of raw sql and return it in an array.

I then transform the array to JSON.  I want to write a test that checks that this transformation to Json is correct.

```
def get_data
  results = connection.raw_connection.execute(sql).each
  transform_results(results)
end

private  
def transform_results(results)
      {
          some_value: results[0]['some_value'],
          another_value: results[0]['another_value']
      }
 end
```

How can I write some Rspec which tests the `transform_results` method to check the Json is mapped correctly, assuming I mock a `results` array.

Something like this?

allow_any_instance_of(?????).to receive(:each).and_return(result)

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should not test private methods - just stay with testing public, `get_data` method.

Here is a stack question: [Should I test private methods using RSpec?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16197332/should-i-test-private-methods-using-rspec/16197778)

However, there is a way to test private methods using [send](https://apidock.com/ruby/Object/send). 
And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4154409/how-to-spec-a-private-method) is a stack question about how to test private methods in RSpec.

To test Hashes (which you might find useful to test `get_data`) you can use [include matchers](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/include-matcher)

```rb
it 'maps results correctly' do
  expect(instance.send(:transform_results, :results)).to include(some_value: 'some_value', antoher_value: 'antoher_value')
end
```